# Generating OpenAPI documentation using springdoc-openapi with spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-rest, springdoc

I've started a new Spring Boot app (2.2.1.RELEASE) using MongoDB.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

To have some API documentation created I added springdoc-api:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
  <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.49</version>
</dependency>
```

As I am relying on Spring to take care of the generation of the REST endpoint, I created this simple repository:

```java
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "profile", path = "profile")
public interface ProfileRepository extends MongoRepository<Profile, String> {

  List<Profile> findByLastname(@Param("n") String lastname);
  List<Profile> findByFirstname(@Param("n") String firstname);
  List<Profile> findByEmail(@Param("e") String email);

}
```

So I have no class with `@RestController`.

I tried to add some `io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations` annotations to the methods in `ProfileRepository`, but nothing gets generated.

```java
@Operation(summary = "Find Profile by first name", description = "Find Profile by first name")
List<Profile> findByLastname(@Param("n") String lastname);
```

Result of `http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs/`:

```json
{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "title": "OpenAPI definition",
    "version": "v0"
  },
  "servers": [
    {
      "url": "http://localhost:8080",
      "description": "Generated server url"
    }
  ],
  "paths": {},
  "components": {}
}
```

How can I have the API documentation generated for my Spring Data REST repository endpoints?

Comment: Have you been able to solve this? It's probably not supported (see https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/298). Also related; My own question on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59868163/why-is-springfox-not-exposing-repositoryrestresource

Answer (score 1):

According to this issue: https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/282, it is not possible to generate the OpenAPI docs from `spring-boot-starter-data-rest` since

> spring-data-rest entities endpoints are dynamically generated at runtime [...]

Quoting from user "bnasslahsen" on the GitHub issue above.

Comment: This issue has been deleted, though it's present on archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/20201217021135/https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/282

Answer (score 0):

As of version 1.2.11 of springdoc-openapi, adding the [`org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-data-rest`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springdoc/springdoc-openapi-data-rest) dependency will generate API documentation for the Spring Data REST endpoints.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
  <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-data-rest</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.10</version>
</dependency>
```