# Why is SpringFox not exposing @RepositoryRestResource?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

I have created a `@RepositoryRestResource`

```java
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "tracks", path = "tracks")
public interface TrackRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<TrackEntity, Long> {
}
```

in addition to some other `@RestController`:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserController {

    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    User postUser(@Validated @RequestBody Credentials credentials) {
        return this.userService.postUser(credentials); // Register user
    }

}
```

In my **aplication.properties** I am setting

```
spring.data.rest.base-path=/api
```

Whereas this is the `@SpringBootApplication` entry-point:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"io.app.spring.repository"})
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
@EntityScan(basePackages = "io.app.hibernate.model")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Application {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(Application.class);

    @PostConstruct
    void started() {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
    }

    @Autowired
    public Application(Environment environment) {
        LOGGER.info("");
        LOGGER.info("Active profiles:");
        for (String profile : environment.getActiveProfiles()) {
            LOGGER.info("  " + profile);
        }
        LOGGER.info("");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOGGER.debug("Running application ..");
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Still, I am not seeing the endpoint(s) for the `TrackRepository` under https://localhost:8443/v3/api-docs. Only those from the `UserController`:

```js
..
"/api/users": {
  "post": {
    "operationId": "postUser",
    "requestBody": {
      "content": {
        "*/*": {
          "schema": {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Credentials"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "default response",
        "content": {
          "*/*": {
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/User"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
..
```

I am using Spring Boot `2.2.2.RELEASE`.

This is the entire **pom.xml** I am using:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>audio-platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>server</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <spring.boot.version>2.2.2.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring Framework Boot -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Docs (Swagger) -->

        <!-- TODO After version upgrades check https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/133 -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.49</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.github.classgraph</groupId>
                    <artifactId>classgraph</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.49</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.classgraph</groupId>
            <artifactId>classgraph</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.44</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Sentry -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.sentry</groupId>
            <artifactId>sentry-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.23</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- PostgreSQL Driver -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Flyway -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb.flyway-test-extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <!-- Java version -->

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

    </build>

    <!-- Dependency Management -->

    <dependencyManagement>

        <dependencies>

            <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>

    </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

I have already tried to add `springfox` dependencies as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56716898/826983)

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-data-rest</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

but it's still not working.

Any ideas what could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

please try to add the `@Import(SpringDataRestConfiguration.class)` to your Application config like this.

```
compile('io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.7.0')
compile('io.springfox:springfox-data-rest:2.7.0')
compile('io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.7.0')
```

```java
    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"io.app.spring.repository"})
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
    @EntityScan(basePackages = "io.app.hibernate.model")
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @Import(SpringDataRestConfiguration.class)//<-- Add thisconfiguration
    public class Application {
```

Example: https://reflectoring.io/documenting-spring-data-rest-api-with-springfox/

Comment: It seems this class does not exist in my Spring version. Or do I have to include another dependency?

Comment: I have added more context to the answer. Hope that helps

Comment: This runs on Spring Boot 1.5.4 though. I am on Spring Boot 2.2.2

Comment: springfox-data-rest version is now 3.0.0 and i got the same issue, v2/api-docs works, swagger / index html is not being shown